# Exclude multiple domains in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

I want to exclude multiple domains from all my reports to prevent referral spam, but as more and more of these popup I'd like to do so via a single filter..

I tried adding a filter with settings:

> Filter Type 'predefined'
>   Exclude
>   Traffic from the ISP domain
>   Tried both 'equal to' and 'that contain'

But it won't let me enter any of these values:

```
semalt|buttons-for-websites|social-buttons|darodar\.com
semalt,buttons-for-websites,social-buttons,darodar\.com
semalt.combuttons-for-websites.comsocial-buttons.com|darodar.com
```

None of these are seen as a valid domain name.

Can I exclude multiple domainnames via a single filter?

Comment: There is some good information in this resource: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/. It mentions semalt, darodar, buttons, etc.

Comment: Flo, I concede your point based upon the linked article and will delete my answer. It is better to have a definitive answer here than a one that may or may not work as advertised as it seems.

Comment: @nyuen Can you write a good answer for us? You can refer to the linked article of course, just give us the highlights in case that link is broken in the future. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are only supported in custom filters. If you want to match multiple domains using a single filter, switch from a predefined filter to a custom filter.

Answer (score 1):

as Andreas mentioned - Regular expressions are supported in custom filters.  Simply create a new filter with the following:

1) Filter Name - whatever you want "**Spam Sites**" is what I use

2) Filter Type - **Custom**

3) **Exclude** (radio button)

4) Filter Field - **Referral**

5) Filter Pattern (here's a list I use - I'm sure there are a ton more)

```
semalt\.com|free-share-buttons\.com|free-social-buttons\.com|simple-share-buttons\.com|social-button\.com|sharebutton\.net|get-free-traffic-now\.com|event-tracking\.com
```

6) Apply Filter to Views - **All Web Site Data**

**Done!**